# Power series and antiderivatives; proof-explanation

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-explanation, power-series

In my lecture notes on power series, I am stuck on a proof of a corollary that states that power series have an antiderivative if they have a positive radius of convergence. I do not understand the underlying logic behind it I think. The corollary uses the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** Assume that the power series $\sum_0^{\infty} a_k x^k$ has radius of convergence $R>0$. Then its sum $s(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ when $|x|<R$. Furthermore, $s(x)$ is differentiable when $|x|<R$ and its derivative is
> $$
> s^{\prime}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k a_k x^{k-1}, \tag{1}
> $$
> which is a power series with the same radius of convergence $R$.

Here's the corollary:

> **Corollary.** If the power series $s(x)=\sum_0^\infty a_k x^k$ has a positive radius of convergence $R$, then $$S(x)=a_0x+\frac{a_1x^2}{2}+\frac{a_2x^3}{3}+\ldots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\tag{2}$$ has the same radius of convergence and $S'(x)=s(x)$ when $|x|<R$.
>
> *Proof.* Termwise differentiation of the power series (2), in agreement with the theorem, gives $\sum_0^\infty a_k x^k$.

I do not understand how termwise differentiation of $S(x)$ is in agreement with the theorem. The assumption of the corollary is that $s(x)$ has a positive radius of convergence -- that's all. According to the theorem, $s(x)$ is then differentiable, but I do not see how that let's us conclude anything about $S(x)$. Why can we differentiate $S(x)$ given the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ and $R'$ of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_{k}}{k+1} x^{k+1}$. Then
$$ (R')^{-1} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} (\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{n})^{1/n}$$
and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (1/n^{1/n}) = 1$, thus
$$(R')^{-1} =\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_{n-1}|^{1/n}.$$
This implies that $R'$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k} x^{k+1}$. Now, if $|x| < R'$ and $x \neq 0$ we have that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k =  \frac{1}{x} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{k+1},$$
thus $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$  converges. It is not hard to see that if $|x| <R$ then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^{k+1}$ converges in a similar manner. Because the radius of convergence is unique, we get $R = R'$ and you can then use the theorem which you first stated.